# Form wont submit to handler in different part of website

Tags: php, html, forms

Alright so, I've been racking my brain, searching the web and I just can't find an answer.
I have my form, pretty easy etc.

```html
                      <form id="loginForm" method="post" autocomplete="on" action="sign/in">
                          <fieldset id="body">
                              <fieldset>
                                  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="User Name / Email" id="email" autocomplete="email" required>
                              </fieldset>
                              <fieldset>
                                  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" autocomplete="password" required>
                              </fieldset>
                              <input type="submit" id="login" data-url="sign/in" value="Log In">
                          </fieldset>
                          <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                      </form>
```

However, when it submits, the Variable $_POST["email"] doesn't get submitted (and $_POST["password"] too..) Anyone have any idea why this is?
It works fine when I send it via GET method.
But for obvious reasons i'm not doing that.

Any help would be appreciated!

==EDIT==
Here is the PHP Code. Keep in mind, its just temp code so its messy.

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(!isset($_POST['email']))
{
  echo "File Not Found";
}
else
{
$u = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]); 
$p = hash(whirlpool, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])); 
$q = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE email='$u' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1");  

//if ($num_rows == 1)
if (mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{           
setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], time() + 2147483647, "/");
setcookie('password', hash(whirlpool, $_POST['password']), time() + 2147483647, "/");

$_SESSION['logged'] = 1;

$qSessions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'");
$iSessions = mysql_fetch_row($qSessions);
$_SESSION['uid'] = $iSessions[0];

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'");

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status=1 WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'");

setcookie('status', $_SESSION['status'], time() + 2147483647); 
header("location:index.php");
}
else
{
echo "Sorry, there is no registered account with that email or the password is incorrect. Please login again.<br />";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your target script really located at `sign/in`?

Comment: The error could be PHP-side, so can you plz show that code too?

Comment: your code work fine.. try to change the action

Comment: After **Mike Brant**: *Is your target script really located at sign/in?* If so, I guess you have `index.php` there? If so, add trailing slash to the form submit action path: `sign/in/`

Comment: *facepalm* That...Worked.... Why does that work (adding a trailing slash) and the other way not work?

Comment: You post data to `sign/in` ,  then your server rewrites path to `sign/in/` where is no more `$_POST`